# Regex edit of a binary file/string using python

Tags: python, regex, hex

I'm searching a way to do some string substitution in python 2.7 usin regex on a binary file.

s is a string I get from reading a binary file. It contains this sequence (hex ) :

'  00 00 **03 00 00 01** 4A 50 20 43 52 55 4E 43 48 20 32 20 45 51 00 **F7 00 F0**   '

here is the variable I use for finding the string to sub :

```
f01 = re.findall( br'\x03\x00\x00\x01(.*?)\xF7\x00\xF0', s)
```

here is my sub :

```
f99 = re.sub( br'\x03\x00\x00\x01(.*?)\xF7\x00\xF0', br'\x03\x00\x00\x01\x4B\x4B\x4B\x4B\xF7\x00\xF0', s)
```

now , while I got no error , my sub doesn't seem to change my string. Am I missing something ?

```
>>> f01 = re.findall( br'\x03\x00\x00\x01(.*?)\xF7\x00\xF0', s)
>>> print f01[0]
JP CRUNCH 2 EQ
>>> f99 = re.sub( br'\x03\x00\x00\x01(.*?)\xF7\x00\xF0', br'\x03\x00\x00\x01\x4B\x4B\x4B\x4B\xF7\x00\xF0', s)
>>> print f99
MThd
>>> print f99[0]
M
>>> print f01[0]
JP CRUNCH 2 EQ
>>> f01 = re.findall( br'\x03\x00\x00\x01(.*?)\xF7\x00\xF0', s)
>>> print f01[0]
JP CRUNCH 2 EQ
```

I would like to have my initial string changed to \x03\x00\x00\x01\x4B\x4B\x4B\x4B\xF7\x00\xF0 so I can store it to a file.

Comment: Thanks , I tried but still the same IMO :

Comment: >>> f99 = re.sub( b'\x03\x00\x00\x01(.*?)\xF7\x00\xF0', b'\x03\x00\x00\x01\x4B\x4B\x4B\x4B\xF7\x00\xF0', s)
>>> print f99[0]
M
>>> f01 = re.findall( br'\x03\x00\x00\x01(.*?)\xF7\x00\xF0', s)
>>> print f01[0]
JP CRUNCH 2 EQ

Answer (score 2):

`r''` literal prefix makes all slashes to be interpreted literally i.e., `r'\x00'` is not a single zero byte but 4 characters.

To avoid a random byte being interpreted as a regex meta-character you could use [`re.escape` function](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.escape).

To avoid repeating prefix, suffix in the replacement string you could use regex' lookahead, lookbehind:

```
>>> s
'\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x01JP CRUNCH 2 EQ\x00\xf7\x00\xf0'
>>> pre = b'\x03\x00\x00\x01'
>>> suff = b'\xf7\x00\xf0'
>>> re.sub(br'(?<=%s).*?(?=%s)' % tuple(map(re.escape, [pre, suff])), b'\x4b'*4, s)
'\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x01KKKK\xf7\x00\xf0'
```

You might need `re.DOTALL` regex flag to force `.` also to match a newline.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, thanks for the answer, this is complex for me to understand. I need to try it & document myself. Anyway thanks for this 'magic formula' , it seems to work as I intend

Comment: @Waraba: You could also generate the regex as: `br'(?<={}).*?(?={})'.format(re.escape(pre), re.escape(suff))`. It might be easier to understand.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: It's a idiosyncrasy (more likely an oversight) that other escapes in a raw replacement string are translated by the re module (for example, `\t` is), but the `\x` escape isn't.